# ASP.NET 5 RC Web API + Framework 4.6 RC Lib

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, visual-studio-2015, .net-4.6

I'm currently testing the `Visual Studio 2015 RC` and encounter a problem that I'm not able to solve.

What I did is to create an `ASP.NET 5 Web Api` project as well as a class library project targeting `.Net Framework 4.6`.

Then, I tried to add a reference from my `Web Api` project on my class library but that's not working. I saw that VS updated my project.json file with the following fragment

```
"framework": {
  "dnx451": {
    "dependencies": {
       "Framework.Core.Launcher":"1.0.0-*"
     }
   },
   "dnxcore50": {}
}
```

The errors in VS are:

`1) Nuget Package Restore failed for one or more packages.`

`2) Dependency Framework.Core.Launcher >= 1.0.0-* could not be resolved`

I'm using the Release Candidate of all mentionned Tools/Frameworks

**Update**

It other words, is it possible to run an `ASP.NET 5 Web Api` project with the folling configuration (project.json):

```
"framework": {
  "dnx451": { },
}
```

and not

```
"framework": {
  "dnx451": { },
  "dnxcore50": { }
}
```

because without the "dnxcore50" (1st example), I have the following error at startup:  "Could not find the `Microsoft.AspNet.Loader.Interop` NuGet package in your users packages folder. This NuGet package is required to run ASP.NET 5 web applications".

And with the second one, it does not compile because my library project does not target dnxcore50...

Comment: Is that a typo or are you missing a `"` in `"dnx451:`?

Comment: It was a typo, thank you for pointing this out

Comment: By the way, changing `dnx451` with `dnx46` does not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this is not possible because the .NET Framework 5 is a subset of .NET 4.6 (and not the opposite!).

I created a new WebAPI 2 project with ASP.NET 4.5 and everything just worked fine...